# How to pass data from view to controller with sample code

Tags: asp.net

I want pass a number from view to controller for verification. Can u help me?(tell me a sample code which i should be writing in view and controller)

Comment: Do you want it in angular ?

Comment: SO is not actually coding service.

Comment: Do you realize that you are not providing any helpful information in order to help you?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41759447/edit) your question to provide a [Minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: "please give me code" isn't the way this platform works. Look at [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience but actually i didnt mean "sample code" i meant an example

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example, following the MVC pattern. This example uses a model `Verification`, a controller `VerificationController` and a view `Add`.

Define a model

```
public class Verification
{
    public int Number { get; set;}
}
```

At the top of your view add this. The `@model` will strongly-type your view.

```
@model Models.Verification
```

Create your form (in your view), remember this needs styling as it's a basic example.

```
//Add is your ActionResult & Verification is your controller
using (@Html.BeginForm("Add", "Verification", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number)
}
```

Now back in your controller, add `Verification` as a parameter. The number property will be filled, now you can save it to the database or whatever.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Verification verification)
{
    int number = verification.Number;
}
```

I hope this makes it clear for you to understand.

Comment: thanks for your help.I got an idea about how to do this